# Como insertar varias filas de un datagridview a sql server en c# mediante dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server

este es el Fomulario en el que estoy trabajando la idea es que pueda seleccionar cualquier checkbox y los que  seleccione se guarden junto con los datos que estan en los textbox de arriba

[image]

Primeramente asi lleno el datagridview

```
 public DataSet llenardataDV(string tabla)
    {
        DataSet DS;

        string cmd = string.Format("select IdRecepcionesPergamino, IdProveedor, IdContrato, Kilogramos from " + tabla);
        //DS = conexionazure.Ejecutaazure(cmd);
        DS = SQLLocal.conexionazure.Ejecutaazure(cmd);
        return DS;
    }

    private void TRASPASOS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.DataSource = llenardataDV("RecepcionesPergaminos").Tables[0];
    }
```

El checkbox lo realizo de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

primero no puedo seleccionar con el checkbox y despues no entiendo como puedo insertar los datos de la fila que se seleccionen por medio del checkbox. 
agradeceria su ayuda muchas gracias

Comment: Muy buenas, Lo primero de todo no veo por ningun lado el evento del checkbox que es el que debe seleccionar la fila. Y Por otro lado ¿Donde quieres guardar los datos en otra tabla? Si es asi imagino que en el botón guardar en el evento click tendras la función para guardar los datos. ¿Es asi?. Un saludo

Comment: Quiero guardar los datos en una tabla en una base de datos en sql Server, y como a hace el evento checkbox? Algún tutorial que me ayude a hacer es?

Comment: Como he puesto en la respuesta si solo quieres utilizar los check para seleccionar las filas no es necesario que lo pongas, sino que uses las SelectedRows del datagrid.

Comment: Ok , pero quiero seleccionar varias a la vez digamos primero la fila 1 y luego la fila 3 sin que la fila 1 se deseleccione, posteriormente, esos elementos seleccionados guardarlos en una tabla de sql server ¿cómo sería para salvar la info?

Answer (score 3):

En base a lo que pude entender de tu pregunta te ofrezco una solución alternativa:

Con respecto a esto *no puedo seleccionar con el checkbox* lo primero que debes verificar es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu `DataGridView` debe tener habilitado la opción de edición, además verificar que la columna que deseas que sea editable en este caso la tipo `checkbox` tenga la propiedad `ReadOnly` establecida en `false`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, asumiendo que vas a guardar los datos una ves presiones el `Botón Guardar`:

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

private void btn_guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("folioOrden", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("tipoMovimiento", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("producto", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("observaciones", typeof(string));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("pesoNeto", typeof(double)); //o decimal
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("idRecepcionesPerga", typeof(int));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("idProveedor", typeof(int));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("idContrato", typeof(int));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add("kilogramos", typeof(double));
 

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value) == true) //True (Seleccionado)
        {
            var filas = dataset.Tables[0].NewRow();

            //LLenando las filas 
            filas["folioOrden"] = tuTextBoxFolio.text;
            filas["tipoMovimiento"] = tuTextBoxTipoMov.text;
            filas["producto"] = tuTextBoxProducto.text;
            filas["observaciones"] = tuTextBoxObservaciones.text;
            filas["pesoNeto"] = Convert.ToDouble(tuTextBoxPesoNeto.text);
            filas["idRecepcionesPerga"] = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.Rows[row.Index].Cells[1].Value);
            filas["idProveedor"] = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.Rows[row.Index].Cells[2].Value);
            filas["idContrato"] = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.Rows[row.Index].Cells[3].Value);
            filas["kilogramos"] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.Rows[row.Index].Cells[4].Value);

            //Agrega las filas al dataset.
            dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add(filas);
        }
    }

    ///Luego cuando vallas a guardar los datos a tu base de datos 
    ///recorres el `dataset` e inserta todos los datos que contenga en la Base de Datos..
    for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //Insertas los valores a la BD.....
    }
}
```

Te explico el funcionamiento:

> - 1ero. Se crea un `dataset` y agregas las columnas correspondientes a cada `textbox` y columna de tu `datagridview.
> - 2do. Recorres el `datagridview` y por cada fila seleccionada, le asignaras los valores al `dataset`.
> - 3ro. Recorres el `dataset` e insertar esos datos en tu Base de Datos de la manera que lo estes haciendo, eso depende de ti.

Espero te sea de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a elaborar una respuesta que te pueda ayudar a falta de que contestes a mi comentario. Voy a suponer que cuando pulsas el check lo que haces es seleccionar la fila en cuestión, y que una vez realizadas las selecciones vas a darle al botón de guardar para salvar los datos en una tabla.

Si la función del check es simplemente la de seleccionar una fila no necesitarías ni ese check bastaría con trabajar con las filas seleccionadas y en el evento click del botón de salvar hacer algo así:

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var selectedRow in dataGridView1_BuscarProductor.SelectedRows)
        {
            //Codigo para salvar los datos.
        }   
    }
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar, y si me das mas datos intentaré darte mas detalles.

un saludo